# AVD with Huawei Mobile Services and without Google Mobile Services

Tags: android-virtual-device, huawei-mobile-services

I am developing flutter app with huawei mobile services.

**To test some things I need emulator with hms, but without gms.**

I've tried creating emulator in avd with system image without Google API, but when I try to install HMS from downloaded apk file I get:

The APK failed to install
Error: Could not parse error string

I've tried:

- downloading different hms core apk,
- downloading app gallery apk which requires hms and installs it, but got the same error,
- changing apk name not to include spaces etc.

No, unfortunately cloud debugging provided by Huawei won't let me test what I need.

Any ideas what is wrong? Why do I get this error? Or maybe a way to remove GMS form emulator?

**EDIT:** Oh and when I try to install hms apk on AVD with GMS it works too, but I need one without GMS...

Answer (score 2):

> To test some things I need emulator with hms, but without gms.

Unfortunately,We don't support it now.

You can also use [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/?ha_source=hms1) or [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug?ha_source=hms1) to test your HMS app.

For Huawei emulator on Android Studio, you can install [HMS Toolkit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881?ha_source=hms1). As a lightweight IDE tool plugin, HMS Toolkit implements app creation, coding, conversion, debugging, test, and release. HMS Toolkit provides Cloud Debugging for you to perform 24/7 uninterrupted testing on your app running on remote real devices. With this function, you can learn about the running status of apps on Huawei devices anytime and anywhere even if no device is available, device types are not completed, or an error cannot be reproduced

Cloud Debugging can be used on a single device for 2 hours each time. Before the validity period expires, you can release the device and apply for the device again.

**Note**: To use Cloud Debugging, you need to sign in using the Huawei Account, complete identity verification, and then authorize the sign-in. Internet Explorer and Chrome are supported. This function applies only to the Chinese mainland, Asia Pacific, and West Europe.

1.You can install HMS Toolkit in either of the following ways:

- **Use the Android Studio Marketplace**

Open Android Studio, go to **File > Settings > Plugins > Marketplace**, enter **HMS Toolkit** in the search box, and click Install. After the installation is complete, restart Android Studio.

- **Import the local plug-in package**

1). Download the [HMS Toolkit package](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Library/toolkit-download-0000001050148172?ha_source=hms1).

2). Open Android Studio, go to **File > Settings > Plugins**, select **Install Plugin from Disk**, and finish subsequent steps. After the installation is complete, restart Android Studio.

2.Cloud Debugging
A. Go to **HMS > Cloud Debugging.**

B. On the **Select Remote Device page**, you can select a required device by **Resolution**, **Android Version**, **EMUI Version**, **Series**, and **Others**. Alternatively, you can use **Available Devices**.

C. Click the selected device.

D. On the menu bar, click Debug to **debug** or run the app on the device. You can also run ADB commands to perform operations. For details, please refer to [ADB commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?ha_source=hms1).